# design pattern for dependent resource in REST

Tags: rest

I am developing specs doc for resource URIs. Most everything is fairly well discussed around on the netz, and is all very helpful. However, I am a bit stuck on the pattern for a dependent resource. So, a **dependent resource** is something that exists at the pleasure of its parent resource. And, if the parent ceases to exist then the dependent also goes away. So, if I have books, a dependent resource would be the count of books. For any given query, if there are no books then there will be no count. Which is different from, say, an author... you could have no books, but still have authors. Ok. So I have something like this URI and the returned data

```
http://example.com/books.json?author=Homer

{"books": [
    {"id": 33, "title": "Iliad", "author": "Homer", "pubyear": "800 BC"},
    {"id": 33, "title": "Odyssey", "author": "Homer", "pubyear": "750 BC"}
]}
```

The URI ends in the plural version of the common noun, and the QUERY_STRING is used to filter the return set. The root node in the return "hash" is the common noun that was queried, and its key is an array each element of which is a hash with key/value pairs.

For the count, my instinct is to do the following

```
http://example.com/books/count.json?author=Homer

{"books": [
    {"count": 2}
]}
```

or even

```
http://example.com/books/stats.json?author=Homer

{"books": [
    {"stats": {
        "count": 2,
        "units": 10,
        "sold": 3
    }
]}
```

But, it seems the correct way really should be

```
http://example.com/books.json/count?author=Homer or
http://example.com/books.json?aggregate=count&author=Homer
```

any suggestions, thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The reason both seem to feel weird is that you are mixing the content type and the content identifier by putting ".json" on it.  The content type should be in the request's "Accept" header.  If you eliminate the ".json", the two possibilities you are considering reduce to the same thing.

That's a purist answer.  If for some reason you must use the extension (framework or client limitations), then putting the extension on the last path element is more standard.

Comment: thanks... good advice. I think I will stick with using the extension as the identifier as it makes for less verbose queries, and more obvious as to what one is going to get back.

Comment: I understand the bit about moving the .json to the "Accept" header but I don't understand how removing that from the URI answers the question in any way.  Please explain what I'm missing here - I'd like to understand where you are coming from on this.